# cakephp remove "NULL" and "0" before/during saveAll

Tags: cakephp

I have a form with a whole lot of "inventory" items, my data looks like this:

```
$this->data['Inventory'][#]['description']
$this->data['Inventory'][#]['quantity']
$this->data['Inventory'][#]['category_id']
```

the thing is I don't know how to unset $this->data['Inventory'][#] if the quatity is either 0 or NULL. I can do this easily with a single record but what is the easiest way to do it with multiple records as above?

my instinct tells me to loop through $this->data in beforeSave() and unset whatever key with and array value with value of 0 or NULL for key 'quantity', is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

The [`extract`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/671/extract) method of CakePHP's core [`Set`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/640/Set) class allows you to filter your data quickly without having to loop through multi dimentional arrays or traverse through tree structures.

```
public function beforeSave($data) {
    // select only the Inventories with a quantity greater than zero
    $this->data = Set::extract('/Inventory[quantity>0]', $this->data);
    // continue with save
    return true;
}
```

The [beforeSave](http://book.cakephp.org/view/683/beforeSave) filter sounds like the correct place for this logic.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$this->data = array_filter($this->data);
```

EDIT: Oops, sorry this doesn't solve your problem. I think you're right, I would probably loop through the array and check the values of quantity.

Comment: FYI, CakePHP offers a slightly customised version of this in its Set::filter() method (http://code.cakephp.org/source/cake/libs/set.php#66)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Nullable behavior a while back that may do just what you're looking to do. It's available on Github (http://github.com/robwilkerson/scratchpad/tree/196e8e8bdbf042f7051f29b077a34ae9265e0983/cakephp/behaviors). It's not as polished as I'd like it to be for public consumption, but it's functional. I'm using it on several projects in production.